# Creating a Shortcut for a Simple Java Application

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a very simple java application that takes in strings and arranges them into lists based on the user's specifications. It has two files. Right now there's no GUI: I run it through the command line. Is it possible to compile it into a program that can be downloaded and run by clicking on an icon even without a GUI (a terminal window will pop up when you click on the icon) and have it still function? If so, how do I do so?

Comment: Package it into an executable jar

Answer (score 0):

If you have Linux & a GNOME desktop, run 'gnome-desktop-item-edit' from terminal, set the command to whatever, and change 'application' to 'application in terminal'. In windows, create a .bat file that looks something like:

```
@echo off
java [-jar] <path to file>
```

And a terminal window will pop up that will exit when the command is done.
I don't know about others, but I'm sure there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
However, there will be some surprising behaviour.

First off, you can double click jar-files to run them. So what you want to do is to build a jar file.

[I find that mkyong has a nice tutorial here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/)

Now of course, that's how to do it manually. What you probably want in the long term is a way to do that automatically.

For long term (I am assuming you're a first year student or similar) use, I'd recommend learning [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). These are tools that will compile your program, test them and if you tell them to, make jarfiles for you.

While I personally find Ant easier to get started with, but Maven is very widespread in the industry.

Now, let's say that you create the jar, you double click on it, and you enter your strings etc. and all is well... And then it all disappears.

This is because Windows will close terminal windows when they're done. So you'll have to remember to ask for an extra Enter keystroke or something before exiting.

This can be annoying but it's not insurmountable.